# How to implement this code using lambda expressions in Java?

Tags: java, lambda, callback, functional-interface

I have a software specification document for a specific library in java which helps collecting data from a biosensor and has a class called 'Patch'. The document specifies:

Following is the constructor of **Patch** class:

```
Patch(JSONObject options, (JSONObject)->onDiscovery,(JSONObject)->ondata,(JSONObject)->onStatus)
```

Where

```
JOSNObject options: options settings for the object
(JSONObject)->onDiscovery: Callback for receiving the sensor info as a JSONObject,
(JSONObject)->ondata: Callback for receiving the sensor data as a JSONObject,
(JSONObject)->onStatus: Callback for receiving the global errors as a JSONObject
```

It should be called as

```
Patch patch=newPatch(jsonConfigObject, discoveryObject, streamObject, status);
```

The concerned fellow stated that these callbacks shall be just lambda expressions.

Now what I understand is:
Constructor takes 4 args:

1. An empty JSON object,
2. Callback function reference
3. Callback function reference
4. Callback function reference

Am new to Callback implementation so am not able to figure out:

1. how shall I implement this one in my code?
2. Do I have to create the functional interfaces for each of those callback methods?

Lets say I have just imported the library, what shall I do next?

Answer (score 0):

The objective of lambda expressions is to denote methods that the `Patch`-object can call (back) at certain events. In contrast to other programming languages it was not possible to pass functions as parameters to constructors or methods in Java. Thus it was necessary to create an object of a class that implements a certain interface (or is otherwise known to have a certain method by type) and to pass it to the method or constructor as a parameter. The method can then be called at the passed object when the event occurs.

The functional interface is already there. You do not need to create it by yourself. It has been already used in the signature of the constructor of `Patch` (the types of the last three parameters to the constructor). Functional interfaces are types which have exactly one abstract method that has to be overridden.

Lets suppose the functional interface looks like this:

```
interface Callback { // could of course have a different name
    public void call(JSONObject o);
}
```

It is not necessary to add the `@FunctionalInterface`-annotation. It would only prevent the interface from later modifications, namely adding further abstract methods.

It seems reasonable to assume that the abstract method does not have a return value (but you need to check this. When you use lambda expressions you do not need to know what the actual method name (here `call`) is.

Although most handy it is not necessary to call the constructor with lambda expressions for the last three parameters. Other possibilities include a *method reference* (using ::),  *anonymous classes*, and instantiating a newly defines class.

Of course you need to know what should happen when the three events occur. Lets say that you have already three methods that provide the necessary functionality. Probably a `JSONObject` that contains information about the event is necessary to do something useful.

```
class Main {
    static void onDiscovery(JSONObject o) {...}
    static void onData(JSONObject o) {...}
    static void onStatus(JSONObject o) {...}
}
```

It is not necessary that the three methods have exactly these names nor that they are `static`.

In the `main` method of this class (or somewhere else) could happen:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONObject o = // ... 
        Patch p = new Patch(o, 
                           (x) -> Main.onDiscovery(x), // (1) lambda expr. (Main. can be omitted)
                           Main::onData,               // (2) method reference
                           new Callback() {            // (3) anonymous inner class
                               public void call(JSONObject x) {
                                   Main.onStatus(x);
                               }
                           });
        //...
    }
```

(1)-(3) show alternative ways to pass an object of type `Callback`.

(1) has the advantage that shorter implementations could go right here instead of calling `onDiscovery(x)`. If you have more than one statement you need curly brackets around the statements and ";" after each statement:

```
(x) -> {
    System.out.println("discovery event");
    System.out.println(x.getXYZ());
    // ...
}
```

(2) has the advantage to be super concise. If you do not have a static method to reference, a object reference can also be used to denote the object on which the method should be called.

(3) anonymous inner classes are would normally not be used anymore for functional interfaces. If the interface / abstract class has more abstract methods but one it is still necessary to use anonymous inner classes.

```
class Main {
    void onData(JSONObject o) { ... }
    // ...
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var m = new Main();
        var o = new JSONObject(); // or whatever
        var p = new Patch(o,
                          (x) -> m.onDiscovery(x),
                          m::onData;
                          new Callback() {
                              public void call(JSONObject x) {
                                  m.onStatus(x);
                              }
                          });
    }
}
```